# iText 5 agregar una linea de texto debajo de un PdfPTable

Tags: pdf, jtable, itext

Aquí esta mi código, lo que quiero es poner debajo de mi tabla : Sub total - iva y total, he intentado agregando nuevos párrafos debajo del código de la tabla pero al momento de ejecutar los agrega en la parte de arriba de la tabla.

```
private void Btn_PDFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 80, 80, 50, 50);
    try {
        FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream("archivo.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, salida);
        writer.setInitialLeading(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add("AIR SERVICE MULTISERVICIOS S.A.S.");
    paragraph.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);

    Paragraph paragraph_2 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_2.add("NIT : 900 818 242-2");
    paragraph_2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);

    Paragraph paragraph_10 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_10.add("\n\n");
    paragraph_10.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);

    Paragraph paragraph_3 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_3 = new Paragraph("Cliente:"+ txt_nombrecliente.getText());
    paragraph_3.add(new Chunk(glue));
    paragraph_3.add("FAC No:"+ txt_fac.getText());

    Paragraph paragraph_4 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_4 = new Paragraph("Nit:"+ txt_nit.getText());
    paragraph_4.add(new Chunk(glue));
    paragraph_4.add("Fecha:"+ txt_fecha.getText());

    Paragraph paragraph_5 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_5 = new Paragraph("Dir:"+ txt_dir.getText());
    paragraph_5.add(new Chunk(glue));
    paragraph_5.add("Tel:"+ txt_tel.getText());

    Paragraph paragraph_6 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_6.add("Email:"+ txt_email.getText());
    paragraph_6.setAlignment(paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
    paragraph_6.setSpacingAfter(10);

    Paragraph paragraph_8 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_8.add( txt_obser.getText());
    paragraph_8.setAlignment(paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
    paragraph_8.setSpacingAfter(5);

    Paragraph paragraph_9 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_9.add( txt_sub_total.getText());
    paragraph_9.setAlignment(paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
    paragraph_9.setSpacingAfter(5);

    document.open();

    try {
        PdfPTable tabla = new 
        PdfPTable(tabla_ventas.getColumnCount());
        tabla.setWidthPercentage(100);
        tabla.setWidths(new float[] {20, 100, 20, 20});
        tabla.setExtendLastRow(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

        tabla.addCell("Cant");
        tabla.addCell("Descripción");
        tabla.addCell("Vr Unitario");
        tabla.addCell("Total"); 

        for (int rows =0; rows < tabla_ventas.getRowCount(); rows++){
            for (int cols = 0; cols <tabla_ventas.getColumnCount();cols++){
                tabla.addCell(tabla_ventas.getModel().getValueAt(rows, cols).toString());

                try {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        document.add(paragraph);
        document.add(paragraph_2);
        document.add(paragraph_10);
        document.add(paragraph_3);
        document.add(paragraph_4);
        document.add(paragraph_5);
        document.add(paragraph_6);

        document.add(paragraph_8);
        document.add(paragraph_9);
        document.add(tabla);                
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
        document.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PDF creado");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Puedes usar:**

```
private Paragraph totales(String texto) {
        Paragraph data = new Paragraph(
            texto,  
            FontFactory.getFont("Serif", 12f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
        );
        data.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        return data;
    }
```

**luego despues de la tabla:**

```
doc.add(totales("SubTotal:"));
doc.add(totales("IVA:"));
doc.add(totales("TOTAL:"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez esto te ayude, yo soy nuevo en java y a traves de esta pagina voy dibujando de a poco el pdf.
http://java-white-box.blogspot.com/2013/11/itext-clases-fundamentales-en-itext.html